How do I search through a specific table in phpmyadmin with the elementor(wordpress) search bar?
So I am pretty new to Wordpress and am trying to build a website. The thing I want to do is to add some tables with people's names and some info about them. Then in the website's page containing a search bar, search through that specific table and display the search results underneath the search bar.
How can I achieve this?
Is there anyway I can query the search bar to search through specific tables in phpmyadmin?
I just don't know where to find the code for a specific search bar in a specific page since there are other search bars than function normally and search through the whole website and I also have other pages with the same function only to be searching through other tables so I don't want to change the whole website's search bar functionality.
I searched wordpress to find a place where I can change the code behind a search bar and couldn't find anything... and I'm kind of scared to touch wordpress files since I might break something and there are too many files and I simply don't know which one contains the backend code for a search bar. I also am hoping to bring the website to a cpanel host since for now it is local. So if the settings or some codes that I need to change are different in local and cpanel host, I'll be happy if you can tell me those as well.
Thanks for your help in advance:)

MySQL or MariaDB is the database system where your data is stored. phpMyAdmin is simply a UI administration tool for MySQL and MariaDB. It allows you to read, write, and manage your databases. Your data persists in the database itself, not in phpMyAdmin

@MohammadSalehi Thanks for the info. Suppose that my website is online and I have my tables in a mysql database in my cpanel host. How can I change the search box's behaviour/query to match what I want it to search for?
